# Stackoverflow Exception caused by property

Tags: c#, recursion, properties, stack-overflow

I have a User class that has a property called Creator which is of type User (the user who created this user)

```
public class User {

    public User()
    {
        UserName = "";
        EmailAddress = "";
    }

    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public String EmailAddress { get; set; }
    //bunch of other properties

    public User Creator { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting a Stackoverflow exception on the line UserName = "";. I am assuming it is because of the Creator property getting stuck in a big loop. Why does this happen if I haven't set Creator to a new User? Is there a way I can stop this from happening?

Comment: What do the `UserName` and `EmailAddress` properties look like?

Comment: You need to post code that 1) Compile 2) Reproduces the error

Comment: Please check how you have implemented UserName or any property which is referenced by UserName. If possible, please post the code here.

Comment: Need the code for the UserName and EmailAddress properties not the Creator property...

Comment: Where and how is Creator accessed?

Comment: Creating this User from a consoleapp works fine for me.

Comment: How about posting code which actually shows the bug? If the code you posted (i.e. the properties are auto-properties) exhibited a stackoverflow in the setter of UserName that'd be a serious compiler bug. But that seems unlikely to me.

Comment: @Rushonerok: Are you sure that's all your code? I am betting that somewhere you are initializing `Creator` which is causing a loop. Then it crashes on UserName because that is your first initialization.

Comment: Do you repeatedly get the SO exception at the same line?

Comment: @Rushonerok: Oh, and I agree with everyone else... more code. In fact, if you can't make your code more easy for us to read by using generic names and removing namespaces and such _PROPERLY_, you're better off just dumping it all untouched.

Comment: Perhaps there is a CreatorName property in the "bunch of other properties" that creates the Creator if null ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you are initializing Creator somehow which is causing an infinite number of User's to be created leading to a StackoverflowException.

Here's an example which produces just that:

```
public List<User> CreatUsers()
{
    List<User> users = new List<User>;

    //Some DB call to get a list of users
    foreach (var record in userlist)
        List.Add(CreatUser(record));
}

public User CreateUser(?? record)
{
    User user = new User();
    //Set properties
    if (record has creator) //pseudo-code
        user.Creator = CreatUser(record.Creator); //guessing as to record.Creator
}

public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        UserName = "";          //Stackoverflow on this line.
        EmailAddress = "";
    }

    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public String EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public User Creator { get; set; }
}
//{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}
```

Actually, I have no idea how to fix it because it's too hard to guess at all his code, lol.

Comment: Well, apparently he answered his own question stating he was doing some loop when creating Users who were their own creators. At first I couldn't think of why that would be an issue because `user.Creator = user;` shouldn't be an issue, but now I can see him creating another instance of that _SAME_ user to set it to the creator, which he does over and over again instead of using that same User object. So his issue was in code he did not post. lol.

Comment: Oh, and my guess was right on, except I'm guessing his `Creator = new User()` is not within the constructor, but rather in his data loop to create users. I'm gonna update my post to show how he probably did it and how he should probably fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I will bet money your `UserName` Setter looks like this

```
public string UserName
{
    get { return UserName; }
    set { UserName = value; }
}
```

This is causing the infinate recursion. You need to either design it like the `Creator` property you had, or do this

```
private string _UserName;
public string UserName
{
    get { return _UserName; }
    set { _UserName = value; }
}
```

EDIT:

I doubt the `Creator` property has anything to do with the issue because that value will just be null in the constructor

Comment: This does introduce an SO exception. But in the property setter and not on UserName = "" in the constructor, as stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have a user where the creator is itself. I guess it was a data problem not a code problem. Thanks for looking at this anyways.

Comment: I'd still say that's a code problem. The code should be defensive and handle such a data problem gracefully.

Comment: I don't see why that would cause a Stackoverflow though. I can do the following no problem. `User user = new User(); user.Creator = user;`

Comment: @Richard I agree. I am adding some additional checks so that the recursion stops if this is the case.